# My website in VisualStudio works well but on IIS did not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, sharepoint, iis

In my website I use Add Service Reference , I read some SharePoint lists,
For the first time I turn on my computer , in VS an error occur !!!
After that it works , and when I want to try on my IIS or Server ISS , the same error occur and did not fix :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Unauthorized
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException: Unauthorized
```

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[DataServiceClientException: Unauthorized]
   System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.Execute() +656
   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute(DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents) +349

[DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this request.]
   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute(DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents) +562697
   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute() +113
   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator() +22
   _default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\user\Desktop\TPPG\tppg.com\default.aspx.cs:58
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3178
```

And this error occur on foreach loop where I want to read data from SharePoint lists !

what can I do !?

this is my code, after Add Service Reference in page load :

```
    ServiceReference1.TPPDataContext obj = new ServiceReference1.TPPDataContext(new Uri("http://sharepoint/_layouts/viewlsts.aspx/_vti_bin/ListData.svc"));
    obj.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
    var sourc = obj.Announcement;

    foreach (var item in sourc)
    {
        if (item.WF1 == "Management1" && item.AnnounceTypeValue == "Management")
        {
            Place[0] = item.Text1;
        }
        else if (item.WF1 == "Sharepoint1" && item.AnnounceTypeValue == "Sharepoint")
        {
            Place[1] = item.Text1;
        }
        else if (item.WF1 == "Admin1" && item.AnnounceTypeValue == "Admin")
        {
            Place[2] = item.Text1;
        }
        else if (item.WF1 == "Training1" && item.AnnounceTypeValue == "Training")
        {
            Place[3] = item.Text1;
        }
        else if (item.WF1 == "Others1" && item.AnnounceTypeValue == "Others")
        {
            Place[4] = item.Text1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, apparently the user account in which context your web app runs doesn't have permissions to SharePoint.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it doesn't work because the application on IIS runs under the IIS user or it's set to the anonymous user. You could try 2 things:

1. Try setting the app in IIS to integrated authentication, if your user has permission.
2. (OR) Instead of DefaultCredentials, set the user with permissions to SharePoint:

   obj.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user",
                                                   "password",
                                                   "domain");